# Visual Studio Code Prevent Accidentally Commit All Changed Files

Tags: visual-studio-code

I uses git as a source control in VS Code. I remember seeing a warning dialog about committing without staging files. I chose "always commit all" or something like that, but now I want the dialog back.

Can anyone suggest how to do it?

Comment: To add to the top answer ^ you can get to settings.json here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908987/how-can-i-open-visual-studio-codes-settings-json-file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`settings.json`:

```
"git.enableSmartCommit": false
```

Comment: Adding this setting does not undo VS Code automatically committing all changed files.

Comment: This DOES undo the automatic commit, but won't bring the dialog back. It will disable the commit button when there are no staged files. For enabling the dialog, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/78139480/1229319.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Git: Suggest Smart Commit -> Reset Setting (or check box).