# How to open Visual Studio Code's 'settings.json' file

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, settings, preference, command-palette

I did it many times, and each time I forgot where it was.

Menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings*.

I get this:

[image]

I want to open file *settings.json* (editable JSON file) instead. How can I do that?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this. But You're looking for `Ctrl` + `,` (or `Command` + `,` on a Mac.) Nowadays here is the [fastest way to open settings.json in vscode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pmhMHAgPPdU), hope this helps.

Comment: No, "Ctrl ," opens settings, it does not open the settings file.

Comment: @sevencardz has the answer for the asked question. Please update the selected answer. Currently it is random stuff unrelated to "click button to toggle between settings.json and the GUI view of it".

Answer (score 525, accepted):

To open the **User** settings:

- Open the command palette (either with <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>)
- Type *"open settings"*
- You are presented with a few options¹, choose **Open User Settings (JSON)**

*This image was taken in the [VS Code online editor](https://github.dev/)*
[image: The dropdown list seen of the "open settings" options]

Which, from the [manual](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) and depending on platform, is one of:

- **Windows** `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json`²
- **macOS** `$HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Code/User/settings.json`
- **Linux** `$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json`

The Workspace settings will be in a `{workspaceName}.code-workspace` file where you saved it, and the Folder settings will be in a `.vscode` folder if and when it has been created.

---

[Official page on User and Workspace Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)

As stated by [sevencardz below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70629074/6091017), VS Code includes a button in the Settings UI gutter which can be used to switch between JSON and graphical view.

[image: The location of the settings UI/JSON toggle in the top-right corner]

The `workbench.settings.editor` option selects which of the settings files is opened by default when not using the above method, such as with the shortcut <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> or through the application menu.

**Footnotes**

1. The aforementioned settings, User and Workspace. Remote settings will appear when using WSL.
2. By a test this maps to `%APPDATA%\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json`, I am not sure by what logic.

Comment: This works for "local" settings, but not WSL, and that's the entire reason I need to get in. Apparently there's still a reference to my old wsl distro name (was 18.04, now 20.04). Know a way to get at that more manually, or where the location should be?

Comment: Found my reasonable solution. Since I was launching code from inside WSL, I created a dependency problem that prevented me from reloading `WSL - Remote` extension. I tried launching code directly from the WIndows .exe, but that didn't help. It then occurred to me to use File -> Close Remote Connection. That eliminated the WSL calls which in turn allowed me to uninstall/reinstall `WSL - Remote` and now I'm good again.

Comment: Glad you worked it out @rainabba. I use WSL as well, and this opens up the `.vscode/settings.json` in my subshell environment.

Comment: is your `.vscode/settings.json` in your project? I think because `.vscode` is related to a project, not the workspace. But how can you create a project settings.json other than [manual](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68166475/1705829) as seen further down? Probably you can create only manually.

Comment: I'm not sure this is true for Windows. Windows 10 has three folders Local, LocalLow and Roaming in the AppData folder.

Comment: Re *"You are presented with two options"*: In version 1.67.1 (2022-05-06), there are six options.

Comment: One or more ([annotated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775)) screenshots wouldn't go amiss.

Comment: The fact that someone had to ask on StackOverflow about "how to view settings", and the fact that so many of us had to Google it, shows how much VS Code needs to be improved in terms of design.

Comment: @AndrewS I clarified this as a footnote

Comment: @PeterMortensen added image links while the imgur integration is down. What six options are these? I count five in the VS Code Online editor

Comment: When you say `%APPDATA%\Roaming`, you mean `%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming`, right? The `%AppData%` env var doesn't point to the `AppData` directory, confusingly. But I'm not using Windows ATM so I'm not totally sure and I can't check.

Comment: Oh, this white label Open Settings (JSON) is just a tooltip of the actual small button. They made it so small I am always forgetting where this is.

Comment: This is 100% not what was asked for. In what way does this switch to settings.json? It does not. It opens settings just like everyone here can already do. The true answer is @sevencardz below: click the magic button in the top right corner of the _active and selected_ settings page.

Comment: With latest VSCode 1.84.2 the steps explained open a `defaulSettings.json` in read only mode. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63211082/cannot-edit-default-vscode-json-settings

Answer (score 154):

On the settings UI page, there's a special button in the top right corner gutter that toggles between the *settings.json* file and the settings UI.

[image: Open Settings (JSON)]

Bonus Answer:

Add *"workbench.settings.editor": "json"* to your *settings.json* file. This will make it so that menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings* or <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> opens your *settings.json* file by default. Optionally, add a comment at the top to remind yourself where the toggle button is.

```
// Click the Open Settings (UI) button in the top
// right corner gutter to toggle the settings UI
{
    // Other settings in settings.json
    // ...
    "workbench.settings.editor": "json"
}
```

Comment: This should be the top answer!

Comment: This is the right answer, the accepted answer is not opening the json file, instead it shows an empty json file

Comment: On Linux, the keyboard shortcut is `Ctrl` + `,`  (comma).

Comment: yes this should be the top answer. thanks

Answer (score 25):

Follow these steps:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
- Type "settings"
- Click on "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)"

[Visual Studio Code Tips and Tricks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks)

Comment: On Mac, presumably? `Shift` + `Ctrl` + `P` on Linux (e.g., with v. 1.67.1 (2002-05-06)).

Answer (score 18):

I show you two ways to open `settings.json`.

### <The 1st way>

1. Open the Command Palette (<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>).
2. Input `settings.json` to the Command Palette.
3. Select `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)`.

[image]

### <The 2nd way>

1. Click on `Settings` from ⚙️.

[image]

2. Click on the mark as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Good to know about this secrete icon shown in the 2nd way.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to edit local workspace/folder settings instead of global user settings, you can edit the file *.vscode/settings.json* (shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and type "settings.json").

If that *settings.json* file or the folder .*vscode* do not exist, you can create them in the folder directory.

These settings will apply to the specific project.

Comment: I needed this local vscode settings file, +1

Comment: Does that work on Windows? Windows has trouble with files and folders only with a file extension.

Comment: I needed this local vscode settings file, +1

Answer (score 7):

These changes are global, so it will affect all of your projects.

1. You can change the *settings.json* file from user preferences.

   Menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings* → *Extensions* → search for "Edit in settings.json"
2. Eventually edit these files directly:

   - Linux: `$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json`
   - macOS: `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json`
   - Windows: `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json`

Comment: I have it located here: %APPDATA%\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json

Comment: On windows 10, AppData has three subdirectories Local, LocalLow, and Roaming but no Code directory as you and others seem to indicate. Dmitry is right its in the roaming folder. It also begs the question why on earth was it place there? It just seems so arbitrary.

Answer (score 5):

To quickly find all 3 settings.json files:

1. Press <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> (or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> on windows)
2. Type `> settings.json` (don't forget the '>' at the start)

The beauty of this approach is it will auto suggest *all* the settings.json files - i.e. user settings, workspace settings, and default settings!

I find that very useful because I don't have to look up each one individually.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

On Windows, the default keybind to open the settings **UI** within VSCode is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>. From there, there is a button at the top right to "Open Settings (JSON)":

[image]

That is one way to get to it. For convenience, I have bound <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> to opening the settings **JSON**. For reference, the setting ID for that is `workbench.action.openSettingsJson`.

Answer (score 4):

> 1. Open VS Code.
> 2. Go to settings by clicking the keyboard shortcut  `ctrl + ,` or with GUI

```
File -> Preferences -> Settings
```

Refer this image

[image: GUI]

> 3. Click on the `Open Settings (JSON)` icon.
>    Refer to the image

[image: open settings.json]

> 4. Once you click on the icon it should open settings.json file

If still, that did not work.

> 6. Go to the search bar and type `json:scheme`
> 7. There click on `Edit in settings.json`. This should work.

[image: edit settings for json]

But still, if it hit you in the head with a brick please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

## In Just 2 steps

**1-** Hit the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
(If you use a MAC it's <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>):

[image]

**2-** Type in the search bar `user settings json`, and finally press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

[image]

**And you're done!** Here you can change the general configs of VS Code in the `settings.json`.

However note that that there are also other types of settings.json which are relative to a project or a workspace for instance.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows:

- Click (<kbd>Fn</kbd>) + <kbd>F1</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> + <kbd>></kbd>)
- Type **open settings json**

Select ***Preferences: open settings (JSON)***

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac the settings file is found at `~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/User/settings.json` - it can be opened from the command line:

```
open -a 'visual studio code.app' ~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/User/settings.json
```

Answer (score 0):

To find a specific setting, it's faster to use the left sidebar search to find the files and lines that setting is in. In my case VS Code kept saying `The setting "editor.defaultFormatter" for Python is set to "ms-python.python" which is deprecated.` despite me changing that everywhere i could find. Turns out there was a nested duplicate in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json`:

```json
    "[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.python"
    },
```