# Can't edit settings.json in vscode, it appears as a GUI and need to integrate git bash within it

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

i want to integrate git bash console inside vscode and i've seen several tutoriales but all of them point that i have to go to preferences and settings, and settings should open settings.json but i get a user interface instead and i can't find a way to get the entire file, instead i get like isolated settings.json files for every element on that interface.

[image: Settings GUI that appears when i click on preferences > settings]

Comment: have you tried one of the buttons in the upper right

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS Code: How to open settings.json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908987/vs-code-how-to-open-settings-json-file)

Comment: That got me too. Thanks rioV8.

Answer (score 1):

**You can find the `settings.json` by:**

- Bringing up the command palette with the keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.
- Then typing and selecting `>Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`
- It's important that you **do not choose** `Preferences: Open User Settings` as this will open the `GUI`.

[image]

I have highlighted the option that you need choose.

Answer (score 0):

To open `settings.json`, press `ctrl+shift+p` and then search for `open settings`. You'll see two options for `json` file. Choose the one you need.