# How could I validate CSS, Less or Sass in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: css, validation, visual-studio-code

Although Visual Studio Code documentation says that `propertyIgnoredDueToDisplay` should result in a "warning" by default, it does not in my CSS file with the following rule:

```css
blockquote cite {
    display: inline;
    margin-top: 0.8rem;
}
```

What could be the reason?

I'm using [Visual Studio Code 1.60.0 Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/).

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio Code's [settings.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908987/how-can-i-open-visual-studio-codes-settings-json-file):

```json
// Enables or disables all validations.
"css.validate": true,
```

[image]

Here is a page to all Visual Studio Code default settings as JSON; you can search "css." to find all configurations: *[settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson)*

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73011545/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.