# VSCode Prettier on save - for Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, prettier, prettier-vscode

[image: ![enter image description here]

## I had

these settings for my VSCode

**settings.json**

```
{
    "workbench.sideBar.location": "left",
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai Pro",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "Monokai Pro Icons",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.renderWhitespace": "none",
    "breadcrumbs.enabled": true,
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "prettier.tabWidth": 4,
    "prettier.vueIndentScriptAndStyle": true,
    "prettier.useTabs": true,
    "prettier.configPath": "/Users/alpha/Sites/notes/VSCode/.prettierrc",
    "[javascript, vue]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
        "editor.formatOnSave": true
    },
    "redhat.telemetry.enabled": true,
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "editor.tabSize": 4,
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascript": "javascriptreact",
        "vue-html": "html",
        "vue": "html"
    }
}
```

**.prettierrc**

```
{
    "semi": false,
    "singleQuote": false,
    "useTabs": true,
    "trailingComma": "none",
    "printWidth": 80,
    "tabWidth": 4
}
```

Right now, it prettifies on save for JS & HTML, perfectly. ✨

[image]

## I want

to make it works with Vue.js.

## I tried

add `vue` -->  `"[javascript, vue]":`

It is not working.

**How would one do that do Vue.js ?**

Answer (score 5):

Adding this block of codes to my main settings seems to work.

```
"[vue]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
},
```

Final settings

```
{
    "workbench.sideBar.location": "left",
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai Pro",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "Monokai Pro Icons",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.renderWhitespace": "none",
    "breadcrumbs.enabled": true,
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "prettier.tabWidth": 4,
    "prettier.vueIndentScriptAndStyle": true,
    "prettier.useTabs": true,
    "prettier.configPath": "/Users/alpha/Sites/notes/VSCode/.prettierrc",
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
        "editor.formatOnSave": true
    },
    "[vue]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
        "editor.formatOnSave": true
    },
    "redhat.telemetry.enabled": true,
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "editor.tabSize": 4,
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascript": "javascriptreact",
        "vue-html": "html",
        "vue": "html"
    }
}
```

***Note: I am not sure if what I did is the right way to do it, but it is working for now.***

[image]

Comment: This is definitely the best way to do it with Nuxt/Vue 3 and the latest vscode in December 2022, thanks!

Comment: For anyone wondering where is the location for *settings.json* in VSCode, you can refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65909052/386579

Comment: Not working anymore in November 2023 