# How to change the highlight color of file in sidebar while editing a file in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to change the color(subtle black in my case) of the file highlighter in sidebar while a file is being edited.

Is there a property which I can change in settings.json to change it?

Please take look at the 1st screenshot, I am talking about the very subtle black highlighting of the "settings.json" in the sidebar while I am editing the file.

[image: 1st Screenshot]

I would like it to be like 2nd screenshot even while editing the file but as soon as I click on the editor it changes to that subtle color shown in the 1st screenshot.

[image: 2nd Screenshot]

I want to achive this while using the same theme.
I hope I am making sense, please let me know if it is confusing, I will try to rephrase it.

Comment: have you looked at all the theme colors and tried to customize the one you need

Comment: Hi @rioV8, Thanks for your comment. No, I am looking for a property that helps change this(file highlight) color for this particular theme?

Comment: it is the same color-name for all themes, you have to change the right color-name

Comment: May I know which particular property you're talking about?

Comment: there are a finite number of theme colors that will apply to the tree list, try the ones that have the word `back` in there name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Open your JSON settings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65908987/3018229) and add the following lines:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "list.inactiveSelectionBackground": "#434343",
}
```

If you want this changed for just a single theme, wrap the inner setting in a `[theme]` block:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[Your Theme Name]": {
        "list.inactiveSelectionBackground": "#434343",
    }
}
```

Comment: this will change it for all themes, better to customize it for a particular theme

Comment: @rioV8 True, I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Hi @carlfriedrich Thank you!! This is what I was looking for.  I mean the type of solution. Unfortunately this `list.inactiveSelectionBackground` doesn't change anything at all, I tried it for all themes and also for particular theme it doesn't work. I wish I could share a screenshot in the comment.

Comment: Hi @carlfriedrich, My bad, I was using `list.inactiveFocousBackground` instead by mistake. Now it works. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

I also found a function( but the solution that ullas kunder gives is much easier):

**ctrl+shift+p**, search "**developer:generate color...**". When you come in, you will find all kinds of color settings. We can add some codes and change colors, too.

Comment: This generates a new theme which then would have to be installed before the settings in there take effect. Seems overkill if you just want to change one color.

Comment: Hah that' true. For if you want to save the change it will let you choose a floder to save it. You comment is very useful!