# vscode transforms <br> to <br></br>

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

When typing `<br>` vscode transforms it to `<br></br>`.

Not sure if it is a plugin that causes the issue or not. Vue3 does not support `<br></br>` and throws an error.

Is it a way to disable this?

Comment: can you please share your extensions list?

Answer (score 0):

It is built-in extension for VS Code called [Emmet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet).
You most definitely can customize it's settings in the `settings.json` file. If you don't know how to open `settings.json`, go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908987/how-can-i-open-visual-studio-codes-settings-json-file).