# How can I auto add 'const' in Flutter in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, constants

In Visual Studio Code, how can you automatically add `const` when you press (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To add an auto const feature when you save the file in Flutter in Visual Studio Code, you should follow these steps:

1. Press (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>) then search for (settings.json) file.
2. Add this code line to there;

   ```
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll": true
    }
   ```

Comment: Is `source.fixAll: true` dangerous? How often does a quick fix suggest the wrong thing?

Comment: @LukeHutchison nope it is not dangerous. But in some places it might delete your comments when you saved the file (but for one year I just faced one time with this situation so it is worth your time GIVE IT A TRY, my suggest).

Answer (score 6):

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
- Search *[settings.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908987/how-can-i-open-visual-studio-codes-settings-json-file)*

  - Open the **User Settings(Json)**

    [image]
  - Add the following code

    ```
     "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.fixAll": true
    }
    ```

Note: It is a simplified and updated version of [Emirhan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73246066/how-can-i-auto-add-const-in-flutter-in-vs-code/73246067#73246067) with required changes

Answer (score 4):

If there are things like constants or changes that can be improved, I recommend you apply for the same Flutter recommendations. Run this in your terminal and that's it.

*[Flutter fix](https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/flutter-fix)*

```
dart fix --apply
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"apply for the same Flutter recommendations"*? Can you elaborate?