# VsCode deactivate yellow curled error lines

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint

I am using VSCode mit ESlint for Typescript.
How can i disable/deactivate yellow curled error lines as shown in the example?

[image]

I only want to disable the yellow. Not the red curly error lines.
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: change/customize the theme color of the warning lines for your Theme to a transparent color or editor background

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yellow wavy lines are warnings. You can disable warnings in the UI by editing the VSCode ESLint extension settings.

Open the file settings.json as explained here: [How can I open Visual Studio Code's 'settings.json' file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908987/how-can-i-open-visual-studio-codes-settings-json-file)

Add this line to the settings:

```
{
    ...
    "eslint.quiet": true,
    ...
}
```

See also the [documentation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint#settings-options).

Answer (score 1):

To disable wavy/squiggly underline in vscode, go to settings, type "Color Customizations" and in settings.json set underline color to fully transparent:

```
{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editorWarning.foreground": "#00000000",
    }
}
```

Comment: This could be nerve-wracking later, since it'll show in styles, but won't be visible.