# Can't open Settings in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, error-handling, text-editor

According to my title, I was stuck in that situation for four months and can't customize my vs code as I desire. So can I know your suggestions?

Here you can see when I open Settings using Windows/Linux - File > Preferences > Settings or Manage > Settings.

[vs code open settings error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INCCj.png)

with hopefully.

Comment: Every similar issues which mentionned this kind of error were because of some extensions. It depends on the 'reading X' thing, one was remote ssh and another was copilot for those I've seen. Maybe try update all of your extensions or your VS Code if you haven't done so yet.

Comment: Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: Thx for all comments that you all advise. Actually, I added the wrong data in settings.json and it made me  unable  to open my settings in vs code.

Answer (score -2):

Click on the bottom left settings cog-wheel icon or re-install VS-CODE. This can be helpful:

> https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

and also this answer:

> [How to open Visual Studio Code's 'settings.json' file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908987/how-to-open-visual-studio-codes-settings-json-file)

from stackoverflow. I hope that helps