Is there a way to programmatically pre-select the Python interpreter in VSCode Server?
we are using VSCode Server (the version for remote usage via a browser).
Our extended Docker image contains multiple versions of Python, in addition to VSCode itself.
The goal is to programmatically pre-select the Python interpreter (or version) that we need, instead of using the default ones in VSCode.
Basically, we want to do programmatically the same thing that users manually do with the "Command Palette" -> "Python: Select Interpreter".
We can use both back-end Linux commands in the container that hosts the VSCode Server and front-end JavaScript.
Is there any way to achieve the goal above?

Can you potentially edit the user or workspace settings.json file? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908987/how-to-open-visual-studio-codes-settings-json-file

You can bash and check "which python3.x" it will give you dir location and there you can change/replace the version of python you want. OR other way is create .sh script to handle this.
